# Searchview doesn't work on Android v6.0

Tags: android, xml, search

Well i am getting so confuse about this one. I create an app that have a search feature, yesterday i test on my Xiaomi Redmi 2 with Android 4.4 and all the feature including search is working smoothly. But today i test it on my friends Nexus 5 with Android 6.1 and all the feature work except the search feature.

When i click the search button, on Xiaomi it will open a searchbar which user can type a text as keyword there but on Nexus it just showing the keyboard and not the searchbar. Nothing happen if i input a text there.

Please master help me. i just don't know what happen exactly.

Thanks..

NB. This my activity that contain the search feature :

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
    ByRentalFragment.CategorySelectionCallbacks,
    ByBrandFragment.CategorySelectionCallbacks,
    ByTypeFragment.CategorySelectionCallbacks,
    ResultListFragment.ResultListCallbacks,
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
private int navigationDepth = 0;
private SearchView mSearchView;
private List<String> suggestions;
private String mCurrentSearchText;
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String subCategoryTitle = null;
private String resultListTitle = null;
private String detailViewTitle = null;
private String searchQueryTitle = null;
private ListView suggestionListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ByRentalFragment(),"Rental");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ByTypeFragment(),"Type");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ByBrandFragment(), "Brand");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<small><small>" + "Cari disini..."+ "</small></small>"));
    int searchPlateId = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    View searchPlate = mSearchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    int submitAreaId = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);
    View submitArea = mSearchView.findViewById(submitAreaId);
    submitArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    int searchImgIcon = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    ImageView searchImgView = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgIcon);
    searchImgView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    searchImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    int closeButtonId = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
    ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(closeButtonId);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearchView.setQuery(null, false);
            UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(HomeActivity.this);
        }
    });

    suggestionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.suggestionListView);
    suggestionListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //initSearchFilter();
    onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(0);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);//percobaan
    if(navigationDepth>=1){
        navigationDepth--;
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        Log.d("navdep", "BackButton " +navigationDepth );
    }else if (navigationDepth == 0) {
        if(mSearchView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    if(navigationDepth==0){

        if(mSearchView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (tabLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        mSearchView.setQuery(query, false);
        mSearchView.clearFocus();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    if (mSearchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        hideSearchView();
    }
}


public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    if (navigationDepth == 0) {
        actionBar.setTitle("RebiL");
    }else if (navigationDepth == 1) {
        actionBar.setTitle(resultListTitle);
        Log.d("navdep", "restoreActionBar " + resultListTitle);
    } else if (navigationDepth == 2) {
        actionBar.setTitle(detailViewTitle);
        Log.d("navdep", "restoreActionBar " + resultListTitle);
    }else if (navigationDepth == 3) {
        actionBar.setTitle(detailViewTitle);
    }else if (navigationDepth == 4) {
        actionBar.setTitle(searchQueryTitle);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mSearchView.isFocused()) {
        mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    }
    if (mSearchView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Log.d("Visible", "Visible Dude");
        mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    hideSoftKeyboard(HomeActivity.this);
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            //if (!isSearchFilerShowing() && !mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())

            showSoftKeyboard(this);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showHideSearchView() {
    if (mSearchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
        mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    } else {
        mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
        mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
        mSearchView.requestFocus();
        showSoftKeyboard(this);
    }
}

private void hideSearchView() {
    if (mSearchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    hideSuggestionList();
}

private void hideSuggestionList() {
    if (suggestionListView != null && suggestionListView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        suggestionListView.setAdapter(null);
        suggestionListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCategorySelected(String catID, String title ) {
    hideSearchView();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultListFragment.newInstance(catID, title),"rl")
            .addToBackStack("catSelect")
            .commit();
    navigationDepth++;
    resultListTitle = title;

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    Log.d("navdep", "NavSelect : " + navigationDepth);

    if(tabLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
}

@Override
public void onResultItemSelected(Item itemDetails) {
    Log.d("ItemDetails", String.valueOf(itemDetails));
    Log.d("ItemDetails", String.valueOf(itemDetails.getCarId()));

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, DetailViewFragment.newInstance(itemDetails),"rl2")
            .addToBackStack("resultItemSelect")
            .commit();
    hideSearchView();
    navigationDepth++;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(itemDetails.getTitle());

    detailViewTitle = itemDetails.getTitle();

    Log.d("navdep", "NavSelect : " + navigationDepth);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(itemDetails.getTitle());
    UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    hideSearchView();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultListFragment.newInstance("", suggestions.get(position)))
            .commit();
    navigationDepth = 4;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(suggestions.get(position));
    searchQueryTitle = suggestions.get(position);
    UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    mSearchView.clearFocus();
    hideSearchView();
    UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultListFragment.newInstance(query))
            .addToBackStack("catSelect")
            .commit();
    navigationDepth++;

    if(tabLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(query);
    resultListTitle = query;
    searchQueryTitle="true";
    Log.d("navdepQuery",String.valueOf(query));
    Log.d("navdep", "NavSelect : " + navigationDepth);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (newText.length() == 0) {
        hideSuggestionList();
        UtilMethods.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
        mSearchView.clearFocus();
        mCurrentSearchText = null;
        return false;
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        //getSearchSuggestions(newText);
        mCurrentSearchText = newText;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Search
private void showSuggestions() {
    if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentSearchText)) {
        if (suggestionListView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            suggestionListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        suggestionListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, suggestions) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentSearchText)) {
                    String text = suggestions.get(position);
                    int startIndex = -1;
                    int endIndex = -1;
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentSearchText)) {
                        startIndex = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(mCurrentSearchText.toLowerCase());
                        endIndex = (startIndex + mCurrentSearchText.length() < text.length()) ?
                                startIndex + mCurrentSearchText.length() : text.length();
                    }
                    if (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0) {
                        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(suggestions.get(position));
                        ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_text_color));
                        sb.setSpan(fcs, startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                        StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
                        sb.setSpan(bss, startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                        textView.setText(sb);
                    } else {
                        textView.setText(suggestions.get(position));
                    }
                }
                return view;
            }
        });
    }
}

private void getSearchSuggestions(String query) {
    String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset(this, "get_suggestion_list");
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        int arraySize = jsonArray.length();
        if (arraySize > 0) {
            suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                suggestions.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
        } else {
            suggestions = null;
        }

        if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showSuggestions();
                }
            });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    hideSuggestionList();
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

And this my xml for HomeActivity :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.gook.rebill.activity.HomeActivity">

<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/hint_color_green"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:fillViewport="false">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value_15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/suggestionListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blankLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/filter_background_shadow_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.gook.rebill.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_30dp"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: It look like you have theme issue with searchview.

Comment: so do you have some advice sir ? @SANAT

Comment: Try using different theme